# TypeError: _save_dispatcher() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fmt'

Tags: python, numpy

People helped me to solve my problem - I am using numpy Version 1.21.0. I am trying to save my data into text file using numpy, But I got problem when run the following code.

```
import numpy as np
import os
Output_path="myDesktop/"
np.save(os.path.join(Output_path,f"labels/{data_type}/{image_name}.txt"),
                             yolo_data,
                             fmt=["%d","%f","%f","%f","%f"]
                             )
```

even try to upgrade the numpy :

```
 pip install numpy --upgrade
   Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\acer\anaconda3\envs\my-torch\lib\site-packages (1.21.0)
```

Comment: `fmt` is a parameter for `np.savetxt`, not for `np.save`.  Reread the docs!

Comment: Thanks , hpaulj, I got  fixed that, but ..I was some different error.

Comment: fmt=["%d","%f","%f","%f","%f"]
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in savetxt
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Anaconda3\envs\my-torch\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1368, in savetxt
    open(fname, 'wt').close()